# How to construct apollo client mutation with custom input and variables

Tags: javascript, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client, graphql-js

I have mutation which works on graphiQL:

```
mutation ADDRELEASE{
  createRelease(release: {
    title: "Release Title"
    releaseType: "Album"

  }) {
    title
    id
  }
}
```

I'm tryng to use **apollo client** with **graphql-tag** and set mutation variables like this:

```
 const CREATE_RELEASE = gql`
  mutation($release: {
    $title: String 
    $releaseType: String
  }){
    createRelease(release: {
      title: $title 
      releaseType: $releaseType

    }){
    id
   }
  }
`
```

I guess it's matter of syntax. Can't figure out how to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to define a variable for both `$release` **and** the other two variables if you're only going to use `$title` and `$releaseType`. You can do either:

```
# Replace ReleaseInput with the appropriate type based on the schema
mutation($release: ReleaseInput) {
  createRelease(release: $release) {
    id
  }
}
```

or...

```
mutation(
  $title: String 
  $releaseType: String
) {
  createRelease(release: {
    title: $title 
    releaseType: $releaseType
  }) {
    id
  }
}
```

For what it's worth, you can also test queries with variables in GraphiQL. You can open the variable editor by clicking on `QUERY VARIABLES` in the bottom left corner of the page.